# Ajax : response value is not the same as in the php file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I am currently working on a **Wordpress** project and I have a issue during an ajax request:

On my view, I have this button for displaying more articles on my page :

```
<input type="hidden" name="nbPages" value="<?php echo $nb_pages;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="pageActive" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="termSlug" value="<?php echo $term_query->slug;?>">
        .
        .
        .
    <div class="product-bottom">
             <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="" id="ajax-loader" style="display:none;">
             <button class="btn btn-site-1" id="loadmore_bt">See more</button>
    </div>
```

On my js file, I have this part that is called when the button is used

```
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_loadmore', 'ajax_loadmore');


$(function () {

    'use strict';

    //AJAX LOAD MORE PRODUCTS

    jQuery('body').on('click', '#loadmore_bt', function (e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      $('#ajax-loader').fadeIn(500);

      var nbPages = jQuery('input[name="nbPages"]').val();
      var activePage = jQuery('input[name="pageActive"]').val();
      var termSlug = jQuery('input[name="termSlug"]').val();

      jQuery.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: "JSON",
          data: {
            'action': 'ajax_loadmore',
            'nbPages': nbPages,
            'activePage': activePage,
            'termSlug': termSlug
          },
        url : ajaxurl,
        success : function(response){
          console.log('cool!');
          console.log(response.newPageToDisplay);
        }
      })
```

In function.php , I have this function which is called :

```
function ajax_loadmore(){
.
.
// set query arg as $args_products
.
.
$products = new WP_Query($args_products);
$rendering = '';
      if ($products->have_posts()) {
        foreach ($products->posts as $key => $prod) {
          $rendering .= "
           <div>
            <h2 class="card-title main-title-2">' . $prod->post_title . '</h2>
            <p class="card-subtitle">' . get_field('reference', $prod->ID) . '</p>
           </div>
           <div class="card-txt">' . get_field('desriptif_court', $prod->ID) . '</div>
           <button class="btn btn-site-1">More info</button>
          </div>";
       }
      $json = array(
       'reponse' => 'success',
       'newPageToDisplay' => $rendering,
       'pageloaded' => $pageToLoad,
       'activePage' => $activePage,
      );
      echo json_encode($json);
     }else{
      echo "error";
      echo json_encode(array(
       'reponse' => $reponse
      ));
     }
 die();
}
```

*My issue is:* $rendering has not the same value than in the js response (as response.newPageToDisplay).
For exemple, on the first element of $rendering is $prod->post_title = 'PA80MP' , while the first element of response.newPageToDisplay is 'PA95'. Both are indeed existing values in my database.

**TLDR :** Ajax doesn't have the same value of variables as in the php file function that it calls.

Hope I explain well my problem ...thank you for helping!

Comment: I'm missing this: `add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_loadmore', 'ajax_loadmore' );` Be sure you that your Ajax-Request calls the right php function.

Comment: @AndyTschiersch Yes, I have already this line above my function ajax_loadmore() in the php file . I forgot to put it on my quoted code, sorry ...

Comment: If you use some test data like `array('test' => 'is ok')`to send it from the php function back to the ajax success function, does it works?

Comment: Yes, a simple string (without any variable on it) does work correctly. If i console.log(response.reponse) it gives me 'success' as well . It's only on the fields of php variables and functions in the while for the value of $rendering that every datas aren't the same

Comment: I can't figure out more. Can it be that you expect other data? I don't belive that the data are changed between php and js. How did you know the content of $rendering? Have you made a dump to a logfile?

Comment: @AndyTschiersch Yes, i made a test by calling my php function in the view , before that, I took the $_POST values from the js (console.log) and set them as raw variables in the function ( nbPages = 2 , activePage = 1, termSlug = 'the_slug' ). the wp_query gaves me the datas that I am expecting though an "echo $rendering;" right before the json_encode ... this is why this issue is so weird for me D: